# Azure API App - Error getting API Definition from SQL Connector Preview

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, azure-logic-apps

I am getting below error after creating On premise SQL Connector and clicking API Definition of SQL Connector Preview APP API.

**Failed to get metadata for 'GetConnector' from endpoint '/$metadata': Failed status code: 'BadRequest'. Response Body: '{ "status": 400, "source": "https://microsoftsqlconnector4d4fb**************6b7f35f0.azurewebsites.net/$metadata", "message": "An item with the same key has already been added." }'.**

I tried to restarted API APP Host/ Updated API. But No Luck. I am unable to create a new SQL connector API APP.

Please assist.

Comment: "I tried to restarted API APP Host/ Updated API. But No Luck. I am unable to create a new SQL connector API APP. "  Seems like you are using the Sql Connector from V1 preview. You should try using the V2preview of logicapp which will not have the host app in it. You can create the logic app and directly select the Sql connector in it, provide the connection info and use it.

Comment: Ping... (if this issue is resolved update/close the question)

Comment: Yes Tushar. I resolved this issue. the problem is in SQL query. I used multiple tables in the select query that time i am getting this issue. then i changed to select the rows and insert to table variable and then finally select the table variable which resolved this issue.

Comment: One more question, Is there any way to upgrade sql connector v1 preview to v2 preview. since sql connector v1 preview deployment template is too complex.